# FullCalendar view rolling 30 days

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am using the [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) library and need to implement a rolling 30 days view using the month grid style view (with day headers, etc). I also need to be able to set the first/starting day in the grid. For example, I would like to have the first day be 5/23 and the last day 6/23 and display in in a month style calendar grid. It is kind of a weird requirement but that is what the business wants. It doesn't appear FullCalendar supports it but was wondering if anyone had tried doing something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be possible because `dayGridMonth` really wants to be an entire month.

This example I made is close to what you're looking for, I just couldn't get the calendar to end at 30 days.

```
var startDate = new Date('2022-07-13');

// This logic is needed because of the way FullCalendar choses the first day
var initialDate = new Date(startDate);
initialDate.setDate(initialDate.getDate() + (7 - startDate.getDay()))

this.calendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'myView',
    firstDay: startDate.getDay() + 1,
    initialDate: initialDate,
    views: {
        myView: {
            type: "dayGridMonth",
            duration: { weeks: 5 } // for some reason { days: 30 } doesn't work
        }
    }
};
```